# large php serialized cache file over 100mb , how to handle?

Tags: php, file, serialization

I have this problem i cant workaround. I cache data in serialized format in a file to be read by php5 and unserialized when requested. Now some of the data files are large 100MB-300MB. I have serialized objects in it.

The problem is retrieving this data will take forever if it ever finishes, currently it fails and reaches max execution time of 90 seconds, setting it higher is not a good solution. I know this is definitely a "code better" idea so I ask here.

I thought of retrieving the serialized data in small portions but unfortunately, serialized data means no line endings. maybe its a noob question but I am exhausted.

thank you

EDIT: I solved this myself. Thanks everyone for your replies. This is how I did it, not the best but its a temporary workaround until 2020A.D.

I "paged " the cache file.

the mutantcode is so

```
for loop that jumps for 10,000 rows
$dataN = array_splice($mydata,N,10000,true)
fputs($myfileN,serialize($dataN))
end
```

edit 2:
So the basic idea was to reduce the file size in order to speed up the process. I narrowed down the serialize/unserialize by splitting the files according to Year/month. The serialized data is emails headers so I changed the serialization to split the data accordingly and the read back in same way. With a small file size everything is atleast operational (which is my job) Eventually it will be easier for me now to migrate to a database and redo this thing. 
Regardless of holier-than-thou(you are wrong comments which is common in IRC/usenet as well) sometimes you have to work with what you are given and make the best of it.

hope it helps someone else.

Comment: Implementing a unserialize that works on file IO is doable, if you know the outer layer is an enumerated array for example. It's not easy, and transitioning to another data format or structuring the store differently is advisable.

Comment: mario, thanks but for now I have to stick with what I have. Any suggestions on how I could like "paginate" the data i am getting from the file?

Comment: Maybe you can store the data in your internal memory (with memcache f.e.)?

Comment: ill try that. but I think the unserialize itself is slowing things down.

Comment: Well, why do you need to serialize so much data ?? Serialization is not a good answer in your case. What kind of data do you store in these files ?

Comment: nopes, its worse the unserialize is the bottle neck
@soju - its cached data like you would have for database results caching. so if not serialized, what would you recommend?

Comment: precisely, why don't you store this data in a db ?

Comment: Show us some code, maybe there is a opportunity for optimizing (freeing) memory while processing?

Comment: I hope it will **not** help to anyone. Means no one would use such a "brilliant" caching solution.

Comment: What about using `var_export()` instead of `serialize()` on those chunks? Something like `$str = '$data = ' . var_export($data, true); file_put_contents($filename, $str);`

Comment: @binaryLV 100MB of PHP code? Are you sure you have an idea of what are you talking about?

Comment: Col. Shrapnel, I know that it is not a good idea, but I'm also quite confident that `serialize()`/`unserialize()` on such large data neither should be done. Though, if Vangel for some reason *has* to do something like that, it would be better to use the fastest possible solution.

Comment: @binaryLV I am practical man. I read some fiction books but I refuse to accept fictional cases in the real life. There is not and cannot be any sensible reason ever. Still your cure going to be worse than disease.

Comment: Did some tests - getting data after `var_export()` is indeed even slower than after `serialize()`.

Comment: i dont know why i was given negative comment etc. i am not saying its a "brilliant caching solution". I just needed help for "MY" special case. sorry if I thought posting here will help someone. thanks for your helpful comments and votes.

Comment: @binaryLV thanks for your reply. I tried it but my problem is reading back the data. I am taking over a project which was as such so I was trying whatever idea I could fine. A split caching is working fine with more ways to split the data. Basically narrowed down so the file size is closer to 10mb rather than 100-300mb.

Comment: @Vangel: You should add your solution as an answer and accept it. This will mark the question as solved. -- The [`Serialized` (PHP Library)](https://github.com/ktomk/Serialized) can parse sessions files. Just in case, just read you solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to my original question for the answer. It's resolved for my case.

Answer (score 0):

An exact case when a cure turned to be much worse than a disease. 
A perfect example shows us why premature optimization **is** evil.

Thank you for providing community with such an excellent example.

Comment: how can you "comment" in an objective manner when optimization or project details was never given by me. Thank you sir but the proverb is not applicable nor helpful.